# Group + ungroup QGraphicItems - find position and scale after ungrouping

Tags: qt, grouping, transformation, qgraphicsitem

I have items, children of various QGraphicsItem, and want to create groups.
I am trying to understand the behavior of grouping - and particularly how to ungroup properly, so that my items will remember what happened to them during grouping.

I need the items' true positions, rotations, and scale after ungrouping, in scene coordinates.

So far I figured out how to retrieve rotation from the group item to pass to child items, but that's all - I do not understand how position and scaling works. (I sort of understand how position works but not how to fix it)

I created a simple sample to check values:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>

void dealingWithGroups(QGraphicsScene* s)
{
    QGraphicsRectItem* r0 = new QGraphicsRectItem(0, s); // some subclassed item
    r0->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable | QGraphicsItem::ItemStacksBehindParent);
    r0->setRect(QRectF(0,0,100,100));
    r0->setPos(QPointF(100,100));
    r0->scale(0.8, 1.1);
    r0->setSelected(true);

    QGraphicsRectItem* r1 = new QGraphicsRectItem(0, s); // some subclassed item
    r1->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable | QGraphicsItem::ItemStacksBehindParent);
    r1->setRect(QRectF(0,0,100,100));
    r1->setPos(QPointF(250,100));
    r1->setRotation(20);
    r1->setSelected(true);

    QString message;

    message = QString("before:\nr0: pos %1 %2 rotation %3 scale %4 %5\nr1: pos %6 %7 rotation %8 scale %9 %10")
            .arg(r0->pos().x()).arg(r0->pos().y()).arg(r0->rotation()).arg(r0->transform().m11()).arg(r0->transform().m22())
            .arg(r1->pos().x()).arg(r1->pos().y()).arg(r1->rotation()).arg(r1->transform().m11()).arg(r1->transform().m22());
    qDebug(qPrintable(message));

    QGraphicsItemGroup* g = new QGraphicsItemGroup(); // actually subclassed
    g->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable | QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable | QGraphicsItem::ItemStacksBehindParent);
    g->setSelected(true);

    foreach(QGraphicsItem* item1, s->selectedItems())
    {
        //item1->setParentItem(g);  // or
        g->addToGroup(item1);
        item1->setSelected(false);
    }
    message = QString("group before move:\ng: pos %1 %2 rotation %3 scale %4 %5")
        .arg(g->pos().x()).arg(g->pos().y()).arg(g->rotation()).arg(g->transform().m11()).arg(g->transform().m22());
    qDebug(qPrintable(message));

    s->addItem(g);
    g->setPos(300, 200);
    g->setRotation(10);
    g->scale(1.5, 1.8);

    message = QString("group:\ng: pos %1 %2 rotation %3 scale %4 %5")
            .arg(g->pos().x()).arg(g->pos().y()).arg(g->rotation()).arg(g->transform().m11()).arg(g->transform().m22());    
    qDebug(qPrintable(message));

    foreach(QGraphicsItem* item1, s->selectedItems())
    {
        //item1->setParentItem(0);  // or
        QGraphicsItemGroup* groupItem = dynamic_cast<QGraphicsItemGroup*>(item1);
        if(groupItem)
        {
            qreal rot = groupItem->rotation();
            foreach(QGraphicsItem* child, groupItem->childItems())
            {
                child->setRotation(child->rotation() + rot);
                // child->setPos(child->mapFromParent(child->pos())); or something, this doesn't work
            }
            s->destroyItemGroup(groupItem);
        }
    }

    message = QString("after:\nr0: pos %1 %2 rotation %3 scale %4 %5\nr1: pos %6 %7 rotation %8 scale %9 %10")
            .arg(r0->pos().x()).arg(r0->pos().y()).arg(r0->rotation()).arg(r0->transform().m11()).arg(r0->transform().m22())
            .arg(r1->pos().x()).arg(r1->pos().y()).arg(r1->rotation()).arg(r1->transform().m11()).arg(r1->transform().m22());
    qDebug(qPrintable(message));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);    
    QGraphicsScene s;
    s.setSceneRect(-50, -50, 500, 500);
    QGraphicsView view(&s);
    view.show();
    dealingWithGroups(&s);
    return app.exec();
}
```

Output: if i set rotation, move, scale

```
before:
r0: pos 100 100 rotation 0 scale 0.8 1.1
r1: pos 250 100 rotation 20 scale 1 1
group before move:
g: pos 0 0 rotation 0 scale 1 1
group after setPos:
g: pos 300 200 rotation 10 scale 1.5 1.8
scene size: 3
scene size: 2
after:
r0: pos 421.674 408.522 rotation 10 scale 1.18177 1.94992
r1: pos 643.256 455.407 rotation 30 scale 1.47721 1.77265
```

So I see that, after adding all the items, the group's position is (0,0) still. And it applies any changes due to group move and group rotation, then gives result based on end position. I have no idea what happens to the scale.

I tried to adjust position using

```
child->setPos(child->mapFromParent(child->pos()));
```

Did not work.

Even with no move, it seems the objects change position a lot - visually, not as if they were rotating around the group center;
Scaling also seems off, why is there any scaling ?

I really need help figuring out how to get item information after ungrouping, based on initial position, rotation, and scale affected by group actions.

I need the items' positions after ungrouping, and also I need the true scale - because I have to apply my own resize operation.

How is it possible for items to appear in one place on scene, and with a certain rotation and scaling, yet report `pos()` and `rotation()` completely different ?

Since I am subclassing all my items - including `QGraphicsItemGroup`, I could override the grouping or ungrouping functions if I could understand their behavior.

Comment: Whilst Qt provides QGraphicsItemGroup, in the past I've found it easier to create my own root level (parent) item, derived from a QGraphicsItem, which doesn't draw anything. The root item maintains its bounding rect as the extents of the items that are added to it (set as children). Perhaps this method would be easier here too.